# Persist nested data to database in one transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have 3 models:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :company_address
end
```

```
class CompanyAddress < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :address, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :address_type
end
```

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_addresses
end
```

I am getting JSON data from another application.

The data consists of attributes of a company and one/none or many company_address which consists of only one address each

I want to be able to insert and update the data automatically and if anything fails I want to role the migration back

When I set `require` on `strong_params` I don't receive the array of company_addresses, however when I only use `permit` it works fine

This doesn't work:

```
params.require(:company)
          .permit([
          :short, :name, :company_legal_form_id,
          :company_role_id, :parent_id, :email,
          :fax, :phone, :description,
          :comment, :changed_by,
          company_addresses: [
              :company_id, :address_type_id, :addition,
              :comment, :changed_by,
              address: [
                  :street, :zip, :city,
                  :country_id, :other1, :other2,
                  :other3, :comment, :changed_by
              ]
          ]
      ])
```

This works:

```
params.permit([
          :short, :name, :company_legal_form_id,
          :company_role_id, :parent_id, :email,
          :fax, :phone, :description,
          :comment, :changed_by,
          company_addresses: [
              :company_id, :address_type_id, :addition,
              :comment, :changed_by,
              address: [
                  :street, :zip, :city,
                  :country_id, :other1, :other2,
                  :other3, :comment, :changed_by
              ]
          ]
      ])
```

So I created a Form-Object called CompanyForm with these methods.

```
class CompanyForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor(
      :company_attributes
  )

  def save
    @company_id = company_attributes.delete('id')

    company_addresses_attributes = company_attributes.delete('company_addresses')

    company_attributes[:changed_by] = 'user'
    company.update!(p company_attributes)
    @company_id = company.id

    if company_addresses_attributes.empty?
      company.company_addresses.destroy_all
    end

    company_addresses_attributes.each do |company_address_attributes|
      @company_address_id = find_company_address_id(company_address_attributes)

      address_attributes = company_address_attributes.delete('address')
      @address_id = find_address_id(address_attributes)

      address_attributes[:changed_by] = 'user'
      address.assign_attributes(p address_attributes)
      @address_id = address.id

      company_address[:changed_by] = 'user'
      company_address.build_address(@address.attributes)
      company_address.assign_attributes(p company_address_attributes)

      company.company_addresses.update!(p company_address.attributes)
    end
  end

  private
    def company
      @company ||= Company.find_by(id: @company_id) || Company.new()
    end

    def address
      @address ||= Address.find_by(id: @address_id) || Address.new()
    end

    def company_address
      @company_address ||= CompanyAddress.find_by(id: @company_address_id) || CompanyAddress.new()
    end

    def find_company_id(params)
      params.dig(:id)
    end

    def find_company_address_id(params)
      params.dig(:id)
    end

    def find_address_id(params)
      params.dig(:id)
    end
end
```

The first question is: why can't I get `company_address` as well when I set require on :company?

The second question is, how could I get my code to work without problems? I know that the code is really ugly, however I am new to Rails and Ruby in general.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the JSON itself - it would help if you provided actual example of JSON sent in that request. The structure could be different than you expect (eg 'company' nested inside of another key).
Try using `binding.pry` at the first line of the controller which handles that request and investigate what are returns from `params` and `params.require(:company)` it might lead you to the answer.

Comment: What was the solution?